# xCode doesn't allow to name an image with special letters

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I want to name images in Assets.xcassets like "a", "á", "â", "ã", "à", but when I try to name an image with "á" and hit 'enter', the name turns into "a-1", "â" - into "a-2" and so on. How can I set image name with this symbols?

**SOLVED**

Check right answer in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was answered on apple forums

> For XCode, if you name images a and à, it considers that it's the same name ; would be the same with a and A.

So I was forced to name my images as

1. a -> a1
2. á -> a2
3. â -> a3
4. and so on

[Check it out here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76647)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to add an image with this name in Xcode 8.3
[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77LYV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your image files before adding to Assets.xcassets, than you can add your files. The rest is same, call your image file like

**Swift 3** and **Swift 4**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "á")
```

**Objective-C**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"á"];
```

Comment: Could you reach the images? If not you put images inside a folder that might be the reason.